# after updated array list not index instantly -react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i need a filter with time "old to new" and "new to old"

here is my code template:

```
  const timeNewToOld = () => {
  const [paginationUsers,setPaginationUsers] = useState([])
    const newToOld = users.sort((a, b) => {
      return b.Time.localeCompare(a.Time)
    })
    setPaginationUsers(newToOld)
  }

  const timeOldToNew = () => {
    const oldToNew = users.sort((a, b) => {
      return a.Time.localeCompare(b.Time)
    })
    setPaginationUsers(oldToNew)
  }
```

this functions working but, not responding instantly on web browser.
i hope i can explain with these images:

i click on the "newtoold" function and nothing changes:
[image]

i move to the next page and i'm back to the 1st page:

[image]

everything is fine. only the first time I click on the function, it doesn't get instant updates, when I change the page, the index returns to normal.

paginationUsers created here:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const getAllData = async () => {
      onSnapshot(_dbRef, (snapshot) => {
        const data = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
          return {
            id: doc.id,
            ...doc.data(),
          }
        })
        setUsers(data)
        setUserPageCount(Math.ceil(data.length / 20))
      })
    }
    getAllData()
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    displayUsers(users, setPaginationUsers, userCurrentPage)
  }, [users, setPaginationUsers, userCurrentPage])
```

i hope i could explain,
happy coding..

Comment: try this one [users, paginationUsers, userCurrentPage]

Answer (score 1):

`Array.prototype.sort` doesn't create a new array, so react can't know that it changed. Creating a new array should help.

```
  const timeOldToNew = () => {
    const oldToNew = [...users].sort((a, b) => {
      return a.Time.localeCompare(b.Time)
    })
    setPaginationUsers(oldToNew)
  }
```